# How to change dropdown font for all the items? How to fit the content of the dropdown in one line without ellipsis?

Tags: css, menu, dropdown

I have some stuff I'd like to change in my dropdown. The website is https://community.entermedschool.com/

Below is the list of things I have tried along with the code I used. But none of them seem to be working...

1. Increase the font size for all of the items in the dropdown menus.
2. Change the font-weight for all the items in the dropdown to 400.

```css
#primary-menu * {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

3. Auto-scale the dropdown size so that all the items fit in one line.

```css
.sub-menu {
    width: fit-content;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
The dropdown with which I want these changes is the primary header which I have highlighted here:
[image]

[image]

I want all of the dropdowns to basically expand automatically so that all of the content 'breathes' in it.

Comment: It is not clear where in the linked page the issue is to find. Please add more details like html in a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Just updated now.

Comment: I answered your question. Please give a feedback...

Answer (score 0):

Your `width: fit-content;` is working but there is no space left for the `::after` (the right arrow `>`). Therefor you could add a `margin-right` to each `li` in the submenu (for example `15px`) and subtract that amount from the `right`-property of the `::after`:

```css
.sub-menu li {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.site-header .sub-menu .menu-item-has-children:not(.hideshow):after { {
  ...
  right: 0; //instead of 15px
  ...
}
```

It works if i change it in the dev tools...